# Pandas row replication python

Tags: python, pandas, replicate

So my dataframe has multiple columns, one of them is named "multiple" which contains boolean, only 1s and 0s. Now, I want to replicate all the rows 4 times only for all the df.loc[df.multiple==1]. How can I do that? (I don't want to replicate indexes)

```
example input:
df=
index strings  multiple
0        A        0
1        B        1
2        C        1
3        D        0
4        E        1


Expected output:

index strings  multiple
0        A        0
1        B        1
2        B        1
3        B        1
4        B        1
5        B        1
6        C        1
7        C        1
8        C        1
9        C        1
10       C        1
11       D        0
12       E        1
13       E        1
14       E        1
15       E        1
16       E        1
```

Comment: create a new df with `df[df.multiple==1]` and use `pd.concat()` to add it 4 times

Comment: But this will not keep the sequence. For example if have df.multiple=1 for index 25, then I need to replicate 25 to 26,27,28,29 sequentially

Comment: Please provide an example input and the matching expected output for explicitness.

Comment: @mozway I have edited and added the example input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another alternative, based on @Vinzent answer.
It is using the same approach to construct the repeats, but doesn't require to reconstruct the full dataframe. It is instead based on indexing. This solution is ~30% faster on the provided dataset and larger datasets.

```
df.loc[np.repeat(df.multiple, df.multiple.values*4+1).index].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [numpy.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 0],
                   ['B', 1],
                   ['C', 1],
                   ['D', 0],
                   ['E', 1]],
                  columns=['strings', 'multiple'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, df['multiple']*4+1, axis=0), columns=df.columns)

print(df)
#    strings multiple
# 0        A        0
# 1        B        1
# 2        B        1
# 3        B        1
# 4        B        1
# 5        B        1
# 6        C        1
# 7        C        1
# 8        C        1
# 9        C        1
# 10       C        1
# 11       D        0
# 12       E        1
# 13       E        1
# 14       E        1
# 15       E        1
# 16       E        1
```

Comment: I have to say that this solution is faster than mine

Comment: @mozway Yes apply is basically a loop. And also pandas tends to be slower (has more overhead) than numpy..

Comment: Building on your answer, here is another alternative: `df.apply(lambda x: np.repeat(x, df['multiple']*4+1)).reset_index(drop=True)`. Still not as fast as yours though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pandas:

```
(df.groupby('multiple')
   .apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x]*4) if x.name else x)
   .droplevel(level=0)
   .sort_index()
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```